# Not able to show store current username name in firebase database with auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Everything gets stored in the database except the username, I am not sure why though, here  is the code

```
nuser= (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()).toString();

userListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
{    

    @Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,int i, long l) 
    {

        HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataMap.put("fromWhom",nuser);
        dataMap.put("imageIdentifier", imageIdentifier);
        dataMap.put("imageLink", uploadedImageLink);
        dataMap.put("des", edit_description.getText().toString());
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference().child("app_users")
            .child(UIDs.get(i)).child("received_posts")
            .push().setValue(dataMap);
    }
});
```

Comment: `(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()).toString();` what is returning ?

Comment: I cannot see a `username` property? About what `username` are you talking about? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo `nuser` here `dataMap.put("fromWhom",nuser);`

Comment: If you are using `Log.d(TAG, nuser);` in your `onItemClick`, what is printed out?

Comment: Does your app crash?

Comment: -LjaEaHcmhX_uSZacx04
des: 
"neeraj"
fromWhom: 
""
imageIdentifier: 
"94932d76-4223-48b7-ae9d-df005f1783e5.png"
so the username is not printed it comes blank for some reason

Comment: you dont have to use `toString()` as `getDisplayName()` returns a String

Comment: @Alex mamo nope it's fine, it's just that the username doesn't get stored in the firebase database

Comment: What's the actual value of `nuser` before trying to write to the database?

Comment: deubg the app and check if `getDisplayName()` is returning anything

Comment: ik @Peter Haddad but even without toString() nothing comes in the output

Comment: I used nunser to store just  the username @Alex Mami

Comment: @NeerajButola Ok but what is actually holding `nuser`? What's the value?

Comment: this is stored in data base

Comment: "-Lj_w9v2zxOMqLpZOqD7" : {
          "des" : "hola",
          "fromWhom" : "",
          "imageIdentifier" : "60e25603-3fbc-4897-8a14-2e336ca4211a.png",
          "imageLink" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/memoii.appspot.com/o/myImages%2F60e25603-3fbc-4897-8a14-2e336ca4211a.png?alt=media&token=227d6026-030d-41cc-b7ed-d3251070d4aa"
        }

Comment: after this line `nuser=(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()).toString();` add `Log.d(TAG,nuser)` -> debug the app -> check the logcat and see what you get

Comment: `.child(UIDs.get(i))` what id is this can you explain sir ?

Comment: It's unclear how the two snippets you shared relate. Can you try this and see if it makes a difference? `dataMap.put("fromWhom", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());`